# SQL : ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'obl2.itemsubjects' (errno: 121)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, create-table

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE `OBL2`.`item` (
`itemID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`itemName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`itemID`) ,
INDEX `itemName` (`itemName` ASC) );

CREATE  TABLE `OBL2`.`subject` (
`subjectID` INT NOT NULL ,
`subjectName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`subjectID`) );
```

Now since the connection is many to many, each item can have many subject and each subject can be related to many items - I'd like to set a connection table.
This is my code:

```
CREATE  TABLE `OBL2`.`itemsubjects` (
`itemID` INT NOT NULL ,
`subjectID` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`itemID`, `subjectID`) ,
INDEX `itemID_idx` (`itemID` ASC) ,
INDEX `subjectID_idx` (`subjectID` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `itemID`
FOREIGN KEY (`itemID` )
REFERENCES `OBL2`.`item` (`itemID` )
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `subjectID`
FOREIGN KEY (`subjectID` )
REFERENCES `OBL2`.`subject` (`subjectID` )
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

but for some reason the code of the 3rd table is not being accepted.
I get an error message:

> ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'obl2.itemsubjects' (errno: 121)

I've read about the error on the internet and it says it's a known issue of MYSQL yet there are no solutions.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you try to insert some data to first two table in the script and then add create table for third table?

Comment: hey bonCondigo, i tried that now.. still same error. I have to say that i did the same thing earlier with authors and it worked perfectly. i can figure why with subjects it fails.

Comment: Is it a must for you to give explicit table names with db?

Comment: mmm i prefer it would be with same names... it shouldn't cause a problem... if i run the query and press "SKIP SQL GENERATION" it works fine. it just won't add the foreign key...

Comment: Try changing the constraint names: `CONSTRAINT item_itemsubject_FK
FOREIGN KEY (itemID) ...`

Comment: Oki problem solved... i changed the filed names and now it works... i still can't figure why the name of field is matter... anyhow thx everyone for your input :)

Comment: The MySQL docs say in **[`FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)**: *"If the `CONSTRAINT` symbol clause is given, the symbol value must be **unique in the database**. If the clause is not given, InnoDB creates the name automatically."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MySQL docs say in **[`FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)** (emphasis mine):

> *If the `CONSTRAINT` symbol clause is given, the **symbol** value must be **unique in the database**. If the clause is not given, InnoDB creates the name automatically.*

So, the reason that the `itemsubject` table creation failed, was that you had another (foreign key) constraint, named `itemID`, or one named `subjectID` in some other table of the database.

It's good to have a naming conevntion that is standard across the database. Just as you have `ColumnName_idx` for indices, you can use `ReferencedTable_ReferencingTable_FK` for foreign key constraints:

```
CREATE  TABLE OBL2.itemsubjects (
  itemID INT NOT NULL ,
  subjectID INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY 
    (itemID, subjectID) ,
  INDEX itemID_idx                           -- I like these 
    (itemID ASC) ,
  INDEX subjectID_idx                        -- two
    (subjectID ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT item_itemsubject_FK             -- what I propose, here
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID)
    REFERENCES OBL2.item (itemID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT subject_itemsubject_FK          -- and here 
    FOREIGN KEY (subjectID)
    REFERENCES OBL2.subject (subjectID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```